# Entity SQL IN/Multiset issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-sql

I am using the following query in entity sql

```
 Select n.Name as NodeNameN  from Nodes  as n where n.Name IN MultiSet (@Test)
```

The value is substitued at runtime using the below code :

```
var reader = model.CreateQuery<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>(
                Statement,
                Parameters.ToArray());
```

When this is executed, the corresponding statment generated in sql server is as below :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Nodes] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Name] = @Test',N'@Test nvarchar(4000)',@Test=N'''BMA'',''Area A'','
```

Instead of `IN` Clause the `=` clause is substituted.

Am I doing any thing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parameterize your [multiset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387137.aspx) with more than one SQL parameter - your current query is interpreted as a multiset with *one* element, so the SQL mapping done by Entity Framework is correct (an IN clause with one element is equivalent to a WHERE clause testing for equality with that element) - just pass more parameters:

```
Select n.Name as NodeNameN  from Nodes  as n where n.Name IN MultiSet (@Test1, @Test2)
```